# Get someone elses public instagram feed

Tags: wordpress, instagram, feed

Lots of widgets and snippets out there for displaying your own feed but cant seem to find anything for displaying someone else's public feed.

Need this for a project I'm working on.

http://instafeedjs.com claims you can get images based on a tag which would almost suffice but it doesn't work so I assume the Instagram API has since been refined.

Why would Instagram restrict access to what is available publicly?

Comment: there are a lot plugins, which can display any public feeds without having access to that account.

Comment: while there are most of them are paid - to show anyone else's account. I have found a better solution

Answer (score 3):

Instagram looks like they did restrict their API but you can still get user info when a request is made with the url below:

https://www.instagram.com/{username}/?__a=1

E.g: This url will get all information about a user who's username is therock
https://www.instagram.com/therock/?__a=1

This was my solution, specifically this applies to wordpress:

```
            <?php 

            // The instagram user eg: elonmusk
            $instagramId = get_field('instagram_id');
            if($instagramId) {
                $request = wp_remote_get( 'https://www.instagram.com/' . $instagramId . '/?__a=1' );
                if( is_wp_error( $request ) ) { return false; // Something }
                $body = wp_remote_retrieve_body( $request );
                $data = json_decode( $body, true );

                // Get the actual user ID eg: 3602415960
                $userID = $data["user"]["id"];

              }?>
```

And then finally use the userID in instafeedjs to display the feed.

```
            <div id="instafeed">
            </div>
            <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/instafeed.js/1.4.1/instafeed.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                var php_var = "<?php echo $userID; ?>";
                var userFeed = new Instafeed({
                    get: 'user',
                    userId: php_var,
                    clientId: '*******Enter yours******',
                    accessToken: '4622774.7cbaeb5.ec8c5041b92b44ada03e4a4a9153bc54',
                    template: '<a href="{{link}}" target="_blank" id="{{id}}"><img src="{{image}}" style="width:25%;"/></a>',
                    sortBy: 'most-recent',
                    limit: 24,
                    links: false
                });
                userFeed.run();
            </script>
```

http://instafeedjs.com

https://pippinsplugins.com/using-wp_remote_get-to-parse-json-from-remote-apis/

I really hope this helps someone else.